# How to permanently communicate with an app

Tags: android

Many apps (e.g. WhatsApp) receive messages on their servers and send them to their app.I want to do something similar, but how?

I thought about a constant socket connection, but this would drain the battery, wouldn't it?

Another idea was to run a scheduler in the app reauesting the sever every few seconds, but this would mean messages will not receive immediately like they do at other apps.

So what's the suggested way to do this without draining the phones battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push messaging.  Which is basically a constantly open socket.  That doesn't drain battery except when actively sending data.  But generally you leverage existing solutions like Firebase, to get around doze rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PushNotificacion. There are many solutions for that like:

- `Firebase Realtime Database`
- `Socket.io`
- `SignalR`

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about Push Notification ?
See here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/